# How to define a user with SELECT privileges with puppet?

Tags: postgresql, installation, puppet

I want to create a user in postgres who can only made SELECT in all the tables of the current database.
How can specify `ALL` tables in puppet?

Here an extract of my puppet file:

```
... 
postgresql::server::database_grant { 'PnBP':
  privilege => 'CREATE',
  db        => 'db',
  role      => 'role',
}

postgresql::server::table_grant { 'SELECT':
  privilege => 'SELECT',
  table     => 'ALL',
  db        => 'db',
  role      => 'role',
}
...
```

But when I specify the word `ALL` it doesn't work.
Here the error:

**Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/Postgresql::Server::Table_grant[PnBP]/Postgresql::Server::Grant[table:PnBP]/Postgresql_psql[grant:table:PnBP]: Could not evaluate: Error evaluating 'unless' clause, returned pid 30443 exit 1: 'ERROR:  relation "all" does not exist
'**

I check the doc, but it doesn't specify how to apply the privileges for all the tables.

> table : Specifies the table to which you are granting access.

[postgresql::server::table_grant](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-postgresql#table)

Comment: I dug into the code for you and found the list of acceptable values for that parameter here: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-postgresql/blob/master/manifests/server/grant.pp#L6-L20. Check how to convert `ALL` into what the module is looking for.

Comment: I've tried setting the value to `'ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA'` which looks like it ought to be valid based on that link, but I just get `ERROR: invalid name syntax` when I try that.

Comment: Looks like this is not something that puppet can handle directly since postgres permission handling is not a simple.
A workaround is provided by on the puppet-users google group : 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/puppet-users/6x2jBEXn-lE/mjr-yXkMBgAJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Puppet documentation for Postgresql describes a postgresql::server::grant option that looks more flexible than the table_grant which assumes a single table.

Looks to be something like:

```
postgresql::server::grant{ 'SELECT':
  object_type => 'ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA',
  object_name => 'public',
  privilege => 'SELECT',
  db        => 'db',
  role      => 'role',
}
```

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-postgresql#postgresqlservergrant

Comment: Thanks, this works for me, it's just important add the `CONNECT` privileges to the same user. thanks a lot.